# Why django throwing error like " 'function' object has no attribute 'order_set' "?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have edited views.py and after that it is throwing error like the screenshot below.
[image]

Here are the codes. 
/apps/views.py contains

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
    
def customer(request, pk):
  customers = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    
   order = customer.order_set.all()
    
   context={'customers':customers, 'order':order}
   return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html',context)
```

and /templates/apps/name.html contains this code to render data from models to templates.

```
{% for i in order %}
 <tr>
    <td>{{i.product}}</td>
    <td>{{i.product.category}}</td>
    <td>{{i.date_created}}</td>
    <td>{{i.status}}</td>
    <td><a href="">Update</a></td>
    <td><a href="">Remove</a></td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I think this error has something to do with order_ser in views.py but i am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: rename `customers = Customer.objects.get(...)` to `customer = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `customers = customer.objects.get(id=pk)`, but then you use `customer.order_set`, and here `customer` refers to the `customer` function. You should use `customer`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
    
def customer(request, pk):
    #      ↓ without s
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=pk)
    order = customer.order_set.all()
    
    context={'customer': customer, 'order':order}
    return render(request, 'accounts/customer.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.